# Email message not correctly formatted with PHP and outlook

Tags: php, outlook

I need to know if there is a way to format a text in the message body of an email in outlook.

I have this part of the message I have to send with mail function towards outlook:

```
Δ request and Δ fault must be....
```

Well, when php script sends email, in outlook I have this formatting:

```
Î" request and Î" fault must be...
```

How should I do to get the greek letter Δ correctly?

Comment: Check whether you've set the right character set for the email

Comment: I have this code set:  $header =  'From:tivoli@inps.it' . "\r\n";
 $header .= "X-Mailer: \n";
 $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
 $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
 $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";

Comment: Please [edit] the question with your code and anything else relevant. Don't bury it, unformatted, in the comments. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway you may need to set utf-8 as the character set instead. Or whatever character set that character comes from.

Comment: THX!! Using utf-8 worked for me.

Comment: To expand on ADyson's comment: a question should be understandable without reading [comments](/help/privileges/comment). Additionally, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. For yet another reason, code in comments is often unreadable. See the [help] for more, especially "[ask]" and on providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Outlook doesn't change the message body automatically. Encoding characters is where you need to pay attention to in such cases. Use `UTF-8` instead of `iso-8859-1`.